# how to dispose JToolBar's frame?

Tags: java, swing, toolbar, visible, jtoolbar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhSE3.png

after i set "toolbar.setVisible(false)" to false , jtoolbar is hidden, but jframe is still on screen ? how can i dispose that temporary frame ?

Comment: for better help sooner post and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with JToolBar

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=d5e5ef54386707302d50687fe39b?bug_id=4418849

Answer (score 0):

I close JFrames with `JFrameName.setVisible(false)` it will hid it but if you want to use the same window again you will have to reset the window when you make it visable again.

Comment: but how to close JToolBar's frame, when you drag it from main frame ?

Comment: Oh in that case you might want to use a listener, one that triggers on the drop so you don't lose the window then you start dragging, and check the number of child elements. You can check this with `JFramename.getComponents()` this will return a component array.  Look and see if the components are still there if not execute `JFrameName.setVisible(false)`.